# How do I upload multiple photos at once to Picasa (Web)?

Tags: photos, picasa

Is there a way to select several photos and upload them all to Picasa?

Answer (score 3):

Solution found!

1. Open GALLERY Select My Library Open up the album that has the photos you want.
2. Press the MENU key ( the one that is left of the home key)
3. Push the 'SELECT MULTIPLES'
4. Then select the photos you want to upload (the pics selected will have a green box with a white checkmark displayed on it).
5. Press the MENU key again, choose QUICK UPLOAD to upload to Facebook Or choose SHARE to upload to Facebook, email, Picasso, print to retail, text messaging, etc.

Voila, your multiple pics are sent!